# Getting error while slicing data coming from server in angular2

Tags: angular

I have below jsondata from server and I am trying to `slice the data` in the method `buildChart(jsonData)` below, but getting `error` as-- `[{"B`.
`jsonData` is not slicing properly while data is coming in the below format.

Please, help finding out the error.

### Format of data coming from server

```
// output- console.log('success:::' + JSON.stringify(success)) 

{"data":"[{\"Brand\":\"Lenovo\",\"Net Sales PRIOR\":\"1200598\",\"Net Sales\":\"1469476\",\"Net Sales CHANGE %\":\"22\"},{\"Brand\":\"Samsung\",\"Net Sales PRIOR\":\"1081820\",\"Net Sales\":\"1194071\",\"Net Sales CHANGE %\":\"10\"},{\"Brand\":\"Dell\",\"Net Sales PRIOR\":\"570745\",\"Net Sales\":\"1128782\",\"Net Sales CHANGE %\":\"97\"},{\"Brand\":\"Apple\",\"Net Sales PRIOR\":\"987349\",\"Net Sales\":\"997392\",\"Net Sales CHANGE %\":\"1\"},{\"Brand\":\"Acer\",\"Net Sales PRIOR\":\"810128\",\"Net Sales\":\"874786\",\"Net Sales CHANGE %\":\"7\"},{\"Brand\":\"Canon\",\"Net Sales PRIOR\":\"494803\",\"Net Sales\":\"677954\",\"Net Sales CHANGE %\":\"37\"},{\"Brand\":\"Sony\",\"Net Sales PRIOR\":\"548727\",\"Net Sales\":\"654016\",\"Net Sales CHANGE %\":\"19\"},{\"Brand\":\"HP\",\"Net Sales PRIOR\":\"409096\",\"Net Sales\":\"548593\",\"Net Sales CHANGE %\":\"34\"}]","meta":"","gtMap":"{}"}
```

### app.component.ts

//Codes above are not necessary,so focus  main code starting from ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(){
let thisx = this;
this.jsonDataService.getPIWSData(this.chartsAjaxMeta).subscribe(
          function (success) {
            thisx.data = success;
            console.log('success:::' + JSON.stringify(success));
            thisx.buildChart(success['data']);
          },
          error => 
            console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
});
buildChart(jsonData){
   console.log('jsonData::::' + jsonData)
  console.log('jsonData::::' + jsonData.slice(0, 10)); //<--- error as 
                                                //jsonData::::[{"B

}
```

Comment: you need to parse the data to get the array of objects and then do a slice

Comment: The above data format is of response from server - console.log('success:::' + JSON.stringify(success))

Comment: buildChart(jsonData){
  console.log('jsonData::::' + jsonData);   // it is providing me array of data.
}

Comment: what is the whole stack trace , my bad

Comment: Can you tell me the desired output you want to get after slice

Comment: First, 10 data after slicing.

Comment: [{"Brand":"Lenovo","Net Sales PRIOR":"1200598","Net Sales":"1469476","Net Sales CHANGE %":"22"},{"Brand":"Samsung","Net Sales PRIOR":"1081820","Net Sales":"1194071","Net Sales CHANGE %":"10"},.....]  (First 10)

Comment: if you can replicate this issue in stackblitz or plunker might be ale to help faster @Ahmadmnzr

Comment: The data is coming from server so I cant demo on plunker.  The response that I am getting as a console.log('success:::' + sucess) is provided above. The problem is it is not slicing properly.

Comment: However, in .. console.log('jsonData::::' + jsonData).... I am getting data as [{"Brand":"Lenovo","Net Sales PRIOR":"1200598","Net Sales":"1469476","Net Sales CHANGE %":"22"},{"Brand":"Samsung","Net Sales PRIOR":"1081820","Net Sales":"1194071","Net Sales CHANGE %":"10"},......]

Comment: you can check stackblitz you can easily replicate it and stub the response, as i dont think slice is the problem it is the data from the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try this JSON.parse(jsonData) save it in a variable

```
let temp=JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

Then

```
result = temp.slice(0,4)
```

Comment: let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    jsonData = (JSON.parse(data['data']));  this.jsonData = jsonData.slice(0, 10);
    console.log('this.jsonData:::' + this.jsonData);